# I can't upload my image from mozilla firefox browser

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento 1.8, the problem is that
when i am going to upload a image it loading the image but after loading the image is not there.

when i test it an another browser it works fine (google chrome).

i checked many process and tested on my site it is not working yet.
but i checked my another site which is done by 1.8 it is working fine.

i am not getting the error yet. i need help.

any one help me on this?
[image]

Comment: Where do you host your Magento? `localhost`? Firebug / Developer Console shows no error ?

Comment: no not localhost http://www.finaldignity.com/ it is working fine on my local, when i upload this to live serve it problem comes up